# Angular gallery plugin

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I'm looking for an Angular plugin that can show pictures like this:

[image]

Something like [this](https://lukasz-galka.github.io/ngx-gallery-demo/), but 
I also need a way to show a caption that is also scrollable and each caption has many images - when clicking each caption it has to be in sync with image on thumbnails (see my drawing). Is there a gallery plugin that does that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made a custom component inspired by cleartrip gallery

https://github.com/aneeskodappana/cleartrip-gallery

Comment: Good work!!  Please accept your own answer, to help others who read this in future